# Window Leak at bottom corner

Tags: windows, leak

We’ve noticed a leak in the bottom corner of a downstairs window. There was always a mark there but it got considerably worse after a recent few rainy days. Any quick guesses for what to look for?

[image: outside corner]

[image: inside corner]

Comment: it is unclear what you are actually asking

Answer (score 2):

First, open the window and check inside the window frame for any cracks. Secondly, recaulk the outside edge between the wood window frame and the brick & mortar. There looks to be some gaps that would allow water to seep inside. The vertical edge on that outside piece of window sill is missing some caulking too.
Think about starting to remove the damaged drywall and insulation which will need to be replaced since the damage is done. You'll have a better clue to exactly where the water's coming from. Wait to make sure the leak is fixed before replacing any drywall and repainting.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if the lower right corner of the outside window sill, (where there is white staining), is deficient in caulk.
Water can enter the crack in the mortar and be wicked up like a sponge.

I would clean and seal that area with a polyester caulk and water test or wait for another rain before repairing the interior.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do would be to check to see if the wood is still solid. Meaning, tap it with the butt of a wooden spoon to see if it sounds Hollow or does it sound like solid. If it's solid then scrape all of the paint from the window seal and around the outside. Clean it up as best as you can and recaulk it and then seal and paint it.

Answer (score 0):

So, awhile back we had some work down around our chimney (removing tar around the base and putting in copper flashing). Magically the window 6-7 feet off center from that work now doesn’t have this leak… I think water was dripping somehow and landing in that spot. Not a satisfying answer but I have no other explanation for it ceasing during a number of subsequent rainstorms. The weird thing is we weren’t fixing an active leak, just repairing old work the prior homeowner had done we didn’t like the look of.